# Twins Paradox: Back on Earth, same moment? (and always)

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, time, observers

Supposing twin A, having been on a well-known circular near-light-speed journey, returns to Earth a younger man than twin B.

Let's say A took off at 3pm and upon return has aged 2 hours while B has aged 4 hours.

Now back on Earth, as they are conversing, would they not agree that they are in the same moment, i.e. they are alive simultaneously.

Assuming they agree that they are in the *same* moment, despite their age difference, is it not fair to say that throughout their separation they are both in the same moment.

Or is the main objection to this simultaneity that the topology of spacetime is unknowable or unpredictable?

*Edit*

The crux of this question seems to be addressed in Thomas Ryckman's 2010 [review of Einstein, Relativity and Absolute Simultaneity](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/einstein-relativity-and-absolute-simultaneity/) where the physical reality of simultaneity is "left to the reader".  Why is the existence of an absolutely simultaneous manifold a matter of equivocation?  Has satellite synchronisation science not settled the matter?  E.g. [Synchronization Gauges](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0409105) & [Sagnac effect, twin paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0403111).

> The Italian theoretical physicist, Selleri, makes another case for
> absolute simultaneity from a completely classical perspective ("The
> zero acceleration discontinuity and absolute simultaneity"). The
> editor of an acute critical collection of essays in an unfortunately
> little-noticed book of ten years ago (*Open Questions in Relativistic
> Physics*, Montreal, 1999), Selleri begins from the often overlooked
> point that our knowledge of inertial frames has been obtained in
> frames possessing some small but non-zero acceleration. Theoretically,
> an inertial frame strictly exists only in the limit as acceleration
> goes smoothly, and without discontinuities, to zero. Summarizing
> previous results, this is shown not to be the case with the existing
> theories of relativity, with examples of both rotating and linearly
> accelerating frames (surely, we knew this already in general
> relativity). Accordingly Selleri specifies a set of "general
> transformations" between inertial systems satisfying the above
> requirement of which the Lorentz transformations are a special case.
>
> These "most general transformations of the space and time variable
> between inertial systems allowed by the continuity condition" yield a
> "general proof of absolute simultaneity" wherein two events judged
> simultaneous in an assumed isotropic rest system `S0` are similarly
> judged simultaneous in the relatively moving system `S`. Moreover he
> shows that this relation of absolute simultaneity can be exported to
> any other inertial system `S′`. While `S0` is privileged (here alone
> Einstein synchronization obtains), it is not experimentally detectable
> and can be arbitrarily chosen. But its existence enables formulation
> of a "weak relativity principle" merely affirming the impossibility of
> measuring the absolute velocity of the earth. Can adherence to such a
> principle justify Selleri's realism — "if a theory describes
> correctly the physical reality, a particular inertial system has to
> exist in which simultaneity and time are not conventional but truly
> physical" (p. 184)? This delicate matter is left to the reader.

A simple explanation of whether absolute simultaneity is accepted or what the problems with its acceptance are would be fantastic.

No doubt with today's news that [Scientists simulate ‘baby’ wormhole](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2022/dec/01/scientists-simulate-baby-wormhole-without-rupturing-space-and-time) will encourage ideas of connecting parts of spacetime leading to the past or the future.  It would be satisfying if it could be plainly shown that all spacetime exists simultaneously and that time-travel portals are a pipe dream.  Of course the opposite would be interesting too.

***An Answer***

As far as absolute simultaneity by satellite synchronisation goes, this evidently cannot be extended universally due to gravitational singularities where relative time cannot be defined and by extension neither can a synchronised time.

Comment: What does “in the same present” mean? That isn’t a phrase that is used in SR textbooks or academic papers. So you will need to clearly define what you mean by it. Either with an experiment they could do or a mathematical formula that defines the concept.

Comment: @Dale In the sense that the present means both what *is* present and what is present *now*, i.e. observed as existing, *when* it is observed (obviously now), then what is present and 'the present' represent the same thing, and "in the same present" is meaningless.  However, some folk think multiple timelines mean there are multiple presents, and that unobervability means certainty of a single present is impossible, e.g. [Science and the Unobservable](https://www.nature.com/articles/140963b0).

Comment: @ChrisDengen What we need is either an experiment that can be used to define it or a mathematical formula. Without either of those I am voting to close this question as unclear. “Some folk think … multiple presents” is a direct result of not having a clear definition of the term

Comment: @Dale It seems quite hard to prove a manifold of simultaneity (a universal present), beyond a basic GPS satellite synchronisation example (maybe that is enough).  Great attempts discussed in this 2008 critique of [Einstein, Relativity and Absolute Simultaneity](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/einstein-relativity-and-absolute-simultaneity/).

Comment: yes, I am not surprised that you find proving things difficult without a clear definition. You should focus on defining your terms first and worry about proofs second

Comment: @Dale The concept of the present seems to involve some existing, living agency to ride the wave of now, like the moving-spotlight, but actually existing.  This is in a different perspective from a timeline from future through present to past.  I am still exploring the science and philosophy of this so I can't give you a complete explanation at this time.

Comment: I would steer clear of philosophy. The divorce between science and philosophy happened at about the same time science divorced itself from alchemy, astrology, and other pseudosciences.

Comment: Physics doesn’t deal with mystical “existing, living agency to ride the wave of now”. Physics needs either an experimental definition or a mathematical definition. It seems like you should be posting this on either a philosophical or religious forum

Comment: @Dale One needs proficient input from both physics and philosophy for this particular topic.  I have been back and forth on it a few times.

Comment: @Dale Physics does deal with the present insofar as it abandoned absolute simultaneity at different places due to unobservability.  What could be the alternative?  Multiple presents?  Would *that* not be meaningless?  What even *could* it mean?  Perhaps some philosophical sense is needed to reinstate absolute simultaneity.

Comment: You said “Would that not be meaningless?” Yes, asking a question with undefined terms is indeed meaningless. That is my concern from the beginning of this conversation

Comment: @Dale I have seen differing opinions about the present, some of which I agree with, others I think are confused.  I am trying not presume my understanding is the correct one but maybe I just have to stand by my guns and say Einstein saying "There is no such thing as simultaneity of distant events." does not mean there is no universal present or absolute simultaneity.  It may be unobservable but there is no rational alternative.  I'm just going to focus on substantiating that.  It seems no-one credible is realistically saying there are multiple presents throughout the universe.

Comment: Einstein is talking about casually-connected simultaneity, e.g. via light.  Absolute simultaneity is already out of the picture due to unobservability, but not out of existence.  The fantasy of multiple presents would, for instance, support dreams of time-travel via wormholes or astral realms.  Never mind, there is just existence; it presents to us in the present, universally.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if your opinion is right or wrong. To have a meaningful question of any kind, you must have definitions for all of the words in the question. For it to be a physics question those definitions should be in terms of experiments or math. By refusing to define your term appropriately your question is literally nonsense (or if you stick with the mystical bit then it is not a physics question). Surely you understand that words need definitions to have meaning

Comment: Inasmuch as the present means what presents itself, it should stick with casually-connected presencing, i.e. via light and observer-dependent (in terms of relativity, and indeed existentially).  In which case 'the present' should be distinguished from 'absolute simultaneity' which is the unobservable entity in question.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I agree with your view that everything exists in the present. The difficulty lies in defining what you mean by a universal 'now' in a rigorous way. It is rather analogous, in my view, to defining a universal 'here', by which I mean that in some way it is misguided.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Thank you.  I was pondering a reply when, 3 hours later [a comment on SE Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/272286?noredirect=1) pointed out that in a singularity [there is no now, or here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity#:~:text=A%20gravitational%20singularity%2C%20spacetime%20singularity,where%22%20or%20%22when%22.)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the returning twin and the stay-at-home twin are reunited in a common present. They just disagree on how much time has passed since they were last  together in a common present (ie when the traveller set off).

Common sense tells us that things that are physically adjacent co-exist in a common present. The difficulty arises in determining how the idea of the present can be extended in a rigorous way across space.

You might have heard of the Andromeda paradox. If I walk directly past you, we exist in a common present. However, because we are moving, my plane of simultaneity is tilted slightly relative to yours. At vast distances, in a far galaxy, the tilt means that what is simultaneously 'now' for you could be ten years before or after what is simultaneously 'now' for me.

The paradox works in reverse, of course. Suppose there are three people in the far galaxy, one of whom is at rest relative to the Earth. For that person, 'now' on the far galaxy equates to 'now' on Earth. But if the other two people in the far galaxy are walking, one towards us and one away, for one of them 'now' might equate to 2032 on Earth while for the other it might equate to 2012 on Earth.

If you now decide to start walking towards the distant galaxy, you enter the same frame of reference as the person on the far galaxy who is walking away from the Earth. But you do not disappear back into 2012.

If you contemplate the example I have sketched out, you should conclude that the idea of the present cannot be extended to cover events that are space-like separated through the usual idea of simultaneity. That does not prove that presentism is wrong- it just means that naive interpretations of presentism, which assume the present is some flat slice through spacetime, are wrong.

My opinion (and here I am straying into philosophy) is that some form of presentism is the only philosophy of time that is logically consistent. If you assume that all matter is moving through a 4d spacetime, and the direction of motion is always forward in a time-like sense, you are implicitly assuming that individual elements of matter exist at a succession of points in spacetime. If you were to be able to travel back in time to 1900, say, you would not find anything there, because you would be in a region of spacetime which all the matter in the universe vacated over a century ago. That view of time eliminates all of the problems associated with the so-called grandfather paradox. The fact that the year 1900 on Earth might be simultaneous with the present for someone walking on a sufficiently distant galaxy does not matter a jot.

Comment: Re. "My opinion (and here I am straying into philosophy) is that some form of presentism is the only philosophy of time that is logically consistent."  I appreciate this comment.  The alternative to absolute simultaneity boggles the mind.  The GPS satellite synchronisation example illustrates the reality.  I will probably pursue in a separate question if there are limits to its scaleability.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a more prosaic example: suppose A and B drive between 2 towns that are 30 miles apart. Before leaving they synchronize their watches and odometers. A takes the highway, which is a longer route (it ends up being 60 miles) but allows him to drive faster (at 60 mph). B takes a straight road which is half as long but has a 30 mph speed limit. They both arrive at their destination at the same time. However, if they compare odometers, A's will show 60 miles elapsed, but B's shows only 30 miles elapsed. Are they in the same place? Of course they are, they've just taken different paths to get there.

Now suppose they both have very accurate atomic watches. Then if they compare times, A's will show a fraction of a nanosecond less time elapsed than B's (yes, really: a miniature version of this experiment has actually been done in a lab, and modern atomic clocks are able to detect time dilation at this scale). But just as they are in the same *place* (despite having different readings on their odometers) so they are also in the same *time* (despite having different readings on their watches). They've just taken different paths through spacetime to get there.

More generally, time shouldn't be thought of as some uniform thing that stands apart from space. Rather, space and time are ways of slicing up a 4 dimensional spacetime, and a "moving" clock will have a direction of time that's different from a "stationary" one (the moving one will have a little bit of space in its ticks, whereas the stationary one has no space). But of course which one is called moving and which one is called stationary is an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not actually touch on the concept of the present, as simultaneity, as dismissed by Einstein: "There is no such thing as simultaneity of distant events." (1949)  I am trying to establish that the twins back on Earth are present together, and in fact that they are always present simultaneously (excuse the tautology), despite time flowing differently.  The following author is addressing the same issue: Hanoch Ben-Yami [*Absolute Distant Simultaneity in Special Relativity*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280671273_Absolute_Distant_Simultaneity_in_Special_Relativity)

Comment: ... where he writes: "This observation of Einstein’s might be misunderstood. Indeed, I think that it has often been misunderstood, leading those who reflected on the nature of time to hold that our pre-relativistic view of simultaneity is a wholesale illusion. I shall try to explain why this is an exaggeration, resulting from a misunderstanding of the sense of ‘event’ as used by Einstein."

Comment: Ben-Yami's paper uses decidedly non-standard definitions of "event" and "simultaneous". The conventional view of physicists is that simultaneity is relative, and that has been the view of the vast majority for over a century now. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity for details. Relativity is not at all controversial among working physicists; it is only those who are newly learning the subject, or those outside the field (e.g. philosopers or theologians) that are confused by it.

Comment: To expand a little bit: it is of course possible to *define* a "present" in terms of some clocks, and to do so consistently. This is what is done in the GPS, for example, where time is defined in terms of an Earth centered inertial frame. The fly in the ointment is that there is no *unique* way to do this; a Mars centered inertial frame would be more convenient for travellers to Mars, but it would not have the same sets of events occurring at the same time. Both definitions would be perfectly (internally) consistent, and consistent with all actual experiments...

Comment: ...but they would disagree. The disagreement would not be about outcomes, but solely about labels (what time labels we put on events). The way we label the world does not change the world, which is why physicists say that simultaneity is relative: different observers may adopt different conventions consistently.

Comment: My concern is that a simultaneous manifold of the present is possible and therefore inevitable, even if it is not practical. In relativity simultaneity is distanced by the causal connection of light, but absolute simultaneity still exists: the Earth travellers and Mars travellers *can* synchronise. Given absolute simultaneity everything in the universe exists together, not phased by different notions of the present, and certainly there is no simultaneous past or future that could be travelled to through a wormhole. Unobservability in physics has nixed the universal present and confused people.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140873/discussion-between-eric-smith-and-chris-degnen).

Answer (score 1):

I'll change the numbers in your question to make it a bit clearer. Suppose that in the traveling twin's (A) watch 10 years have passed, while 50 years have passed in the watch of the twin that stayed at the Earth (B). These numbers are more shocking, so the effects are easier to visualize.

Both twins agree that A looks way younger. Both twins agree that B looks old. Both twins agree that the puppy they got just before A traveled has died of old age and that its grandpuppies are in the living room with them. They both agree on reality and that 50 years have passed on Earth, but A experienced less time.

The point is not on whether spacetime is homogeneous or anything of the sort. This would happen in a perfectly homogeneous and isotropic spacetime (which is assumed in special relativity). A ages less because time is not an universal property. In geometrical terms, this is exactly analogous to how you can connect two points with either a straight line or a circular arc and they will have different arc lengths. The arc length is not a property of the points, but of the path. Similarly, time is a property of the path through spacetime, not of the initial and final event.

The twins might disagree on the wording. They might disagree on whether the last time they had a beer together was fifty years ago or ten years ago. They might disagree on whether its 2032 or 2072. But these are just words and labels. It is similar to how people in the US and in the UK might disagree on what the word "football" means. The "paradox" is they are trying to use the same words to mean different things (each of them means something different when they say 2032, each of the countries means a different sport), or different words to mean the same thing (10 years ago or 50 years ago, "soccer" or "football"). However, they agree on all physical predictions. There is no physical paradox, there is no logical paradox, there is no philosophical paradox. There is just a linguistic confusion because our usual, intuitive understanding of space and time does not match how actual space and time behave.

Comment: If you're reading this answer 10 or 50 years in the future, you might enjoy the Easter egg that it was written during the World Cup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am interested in how they adjust this conception of time difference, or age difference, when they are back together on Earth.  Do they now accept that they are together at the same 'time', or rather 'in the present'.  The word 'time' here now plays two roles: the different times on their respective calendars, and the rolling instance of the present in which they are chatting.  Or perhaps the notion of time should be separated from the notion of the present, because clearly they have two different times but only one present.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen They do accept and understand they are now together in the present and at the same time. There might be a sociological (not physical) unconvenience that either A has to skip 40 years in their calendar or B has to go back 40 years for them both to say "Today is November 26, 20XY" together, but that is just a matter of labelling. They might tag the same day with different names, but both agree they are together at the same time. The present.

Comment: Their calendars do read differently though. A's calendar does read 2032, while B's reads 2072. However, this is just a linguistic difference. They still agree they are both on the present.

Comment: And half-way round A's journey, assuming uniform spacetime, do A and B still exist at the same time, in the present?

Comment: @ChrisDegnen There are different interpretations. Simultaneity is not an absolute concept. It does not make sense to speak of "present" at large distances. In fact, the notion of "present" is ill-defined in relativity, and I used the word in the previous comments in more of a common-sense fashion, which works as an approximation for observers that are at rest and sufficiently close to each other. In more general situations, the word "present" only has meaning if you choose a convention to define it

Comment: Hence, half-way the journey, it doesn't make sense to ask where they are "at the same time". It doesn't make sense to ask what is happening *now* at Andromeda without saying which arbitrarily chosen convention of simultaneity you are using. In Relativity, past and future are important and well-defined concepts, but the present is only an approximate notion used in some situations that resemble day-to-day conditions sufficiently well. Otherwise, we just say the events are spacelike related.

Comment: Re. "half-way [through] the journey, it doesn't make sense to ask where they are 'at the same time'."  With a circular journey, at half-way, could not A and B each send a light pulse toward each other which would meet in the exact middle, thus demonstrating that they were simultaneous when the pulses were sent?

Comment: Re. "the notion of 'present' is ill-defined in relativity."  I would agree.  I have been reading up on the moving-spotlight theory but every version seems to differ and I don't agree with any of them so far.  There is a whole taxonomy here: [The Moving Spotlight: An Essay on Time and Ontology](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/the-moving-spotlight-an-essay-on-time-and-ontology/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140865/discussion-between-nickolas-alves-and-chris-degnen).